# Can a server which acts both as RMI and UDP server listen to requests on the same port number?

Tags: sockets, udp, port, rmi, udpclient

I'm working on a program in which a UDP server keeps listening to incoming requests.
If a particluar kind of request is received, it tries to create a RMI server using the same port on which the UDP server was listening.

So, is this possible?
or I need to have different ports?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. TCP and UDP port numbers are in different namespaces.